# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in Express.js

Tags: node.js, json, express

I read json file to query with req.params and I want to return res.json but I get error from express.js

```
_http_outgoing.js:482
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

in route.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  app.get('/find/:province', province.find);
}
```

in controller.js

```
exports.find = function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./app/models/province_file.json', function(err, provinces){
    if (err) throw err;
    let obj_provinces = JSON.parse(provinces);
    let province = req.params.province;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj_provinces.features.length; i++) {
      if (obj_provinces.features[i].properties.tb_tn == province) {
        let obj_result = obj_provinces.features[i].properties;
        console.log(obj_result);
        res.json(obj_result);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

when I run the code I get error

```
_http_outgoing.js:482
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)
    at /Users/workspace/app/controllers/controller.js:87:13
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:54:3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not call `res.json(obj_result);` in for loop, let your loop done the work then call 
 `res.json(obj_result);`;

Because in `if` `res.json(obj_result)` is getting called more than once that's why you are getting this error.

It's best practice to use `return` when you done the execution, it make sure execution is ended at that point.

```
return res.json(obj_result);
```

Comment: oh, thank you I try return res.json(obj_result); but I get 1 object from 15 object. I wrong?

Comment: Please refer back to this comment, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086621/6076712)
and yes you are trying to override response in a for loop